# results of is_dir are cached?

Tags: php, loops, directory

I have built a simple function to wait for another process to finish (on a linux system):

```
function WaitPID($pid)
{
    while (is_dir('/proc/' . $pid))
        usleep(2500);
    return true;
}
```

However, this function never returns, causing the script to hang indefinitely.

Is the result of `is_dir()` cached or am I doing something wrong?

In any case, how do I fix my function to work as expected?

Comment: Not sure whether it's cached, but try doing a `clearstatcache()` prior to each loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, see "Note: The results of this function are cached. See clearstatcache() for more details."

See the php function for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php